# Laravel 5.5/Scout: how to extend Scout to use joins?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, relationship, laravel-scout

I am using Laravel/Scout/Elasticsearch via https://packagist.org/packages/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver and I have this situation:

1. To search, I must use a model like this:

   `$visits = Visit::search("canada")->with(['origin', 'profile', 'user'])->paginate(10);`

It works very well.

2. As you can see, this model is related to three other tables: origins (that are countries), profile and users. The way the everything is set, I can search for "canada" and get all the visits that came from Canada, what is fine as well.
3. The result is shown in a grid using paginate(), what works well, too.
4. However, if I want to sort the grid by Origins -- for everything I read and tried so far -- I can't use the `$model->with(...)` approach. Instead, I have to use something like

   `$visits = DB::table('visits') 
   ->join('origins', 'origins.id', 'visits.origin_id')
   ->orderby($sort_column, $sort_az_za)
   ->paginate(10);`
5. This is the thing: the search() will not work with the `DB::table('visits')` 
   syntax and 
   `Visit::search("canada")->with(....)...`
   approach does not allow me to sort by a field that is not in the Visits table.

The question is: how can I search and sort the results by any field I want?

I thought that it should be possible to extend Scout to search  DB::table('TABLE') or to try to sort directly via ES  -- though I would prefer to keep all the code bound to the "Laravel way".

If extending the DB::table('TABLE') is a way, could someone point me where to start?

Other than that, any other ideas?

Comment: You can use `->join()` on `Visit` model. `Visit::join('origins', 'origins.id', 'visits.origin_id')...`

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before. While
`Visit::join('origins', 'origins.id', 'visits.origin_id')->get()` works, 
`Visit::join('origins', 'origins.id', 'visits.origin_id')->search('canada')->get()` 
will throw this error:

`BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()'`

This is exactly the problem: the query builder does not recognize search() as a valid method.

Comment: I am keeping this thread here: 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-55scout-how-to-extend-scout-to-use-eloquent-joins